# Возможно ли в Hibernate при связывании таблиц (@OneToMany @ManyToOne) получить вместо объекта только поле Id?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Суть проблемы в том что у меня Класс связанный в древовидную структуру по принципу предок/потомки, но когда я получаю объект у которого есть предок и потомки из БД вытягиваются не только эти объекты, но и объекты связанные с предком и потомками, а мне достаточно было бы получать только Id предка и списки List Id потомков, возможно ли связывать таблицы и получать только их Id, не вытягивая из БД весь остальной фарш?

сейчас так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="testpage")
public class TestPage {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long Id;
    @Column(unique=true,nullable=false)
    private String Name;
    private int position;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn()
    @JoinTable(name="parent_testpage",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private TestPage Parent;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="parent_testpage",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<TestPage> Child;

    ...getters and setters
}
```

хотелось бы так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="testpage")
public class TestPage {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long Id;
    @Column(unique=true,nullable=false)
    private String Name;
    private int position;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn()
    @JoinTable(name="parent_testpage",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private long ParentId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="parent_testpage",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<Long> ChildIds;

...getters and setters

}
```

Comment: Если речь идёт о JPA. Там есть возможность получить та называемую ссылку на объект. Это объект, у которого из всех полей загружен только ID. Не совсем конечно одиночный ID, но тем не менее не всё тянет из базы. Надо посмотреть документацию, может есть какой-то хинт для запроса, чтобы и OneToMany в таком виде извлечь.

Comment: Другой вариант извлекать ID через специальный запрос. Правда и результаты будут отдельным списком, а не в entity.childs.

Comment: @banme запрос, как я понимаю, уже будет сделан через DAO класс или его можно встроить в Entity-класс?

Comment: Запрос В DAO. В entity разве что namedquery "встроить" (что равносильно на самом деле "в DAO"). Этот вариант кажется Ruslan и предлагает в своём ответе

Comment: @banme Я нашел способ получить только Id предка, таким образом
`@JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id"))
 private Long parentId;`
Но не нашел подобного способа получить List Idшников потомков =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу оговорюсь, что это касается JPA. У Hibernate есть ещё какие-то свои родные механизмы - я их не знаю.

Только отдельный запрос, как говорит Ruslan Nekura, поможет получить id child-ов.
(Но есть ещё один вариант. О нём чуть ниже)

Не работает JPA по-другому. Не ссылается он на отдельные поля других entity.  Только на объект целиком.
parent_Id - это поле в того же самого entity. Оно может быть использовано и так и сяк и даже одновременно:

```
...
@JoinTable(name="parent_testpage",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
private TestPage Parent;

@Column(name="parent_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Long parentId;
...
```

Если используются одновременно, то одно отображение обязательно отметить как "только для чтения". В примере это parentId с параметрами аннотации insertable, updatable = false.

Со списком child-ов, как уже сказано выше, такой номер не пройдёт.

И вот ещё одна метода.
Можно сделать view в базе с полями parent_id и child_id.

```
CREATE VIEW view_child_ids (long parent_id, long child_id) AS 
SELECT parent_id, id FROM testpage WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Отобразить эту view в виде Basic ElementCollection:

```
...
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "view_child_ids",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"))
@Column(name = "child_id")
private List<Long> childIds;
...
```

Для этой view ещё надо будет всяких правил/триггеров определить на случай каскадных удаления/изменения.
Есть в этом свои недостатки, но не буду их упоминать. Они проявляются при определённых обстоятельствах. Может Вам повезёт, ведь никто не знает всей Вашей задумки. Сам предпочитаю запросы.

Радикальный вариант - уйти с JPA/Hibernate на альтернативный способ доступа к данным, работающий на других принципах. Active-record какой-нибудь.

Comment: Благодарю, это уже ближе к делу. я немного поменял Ваш пример, у меня заработало!!! )))
Теперь так:
`@JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id"))
private Long parentId;

@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "parent_ttp", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@Column(name = "child_id")
private List<Long> childIds = new ArrayList<Long>();`

Answer (score 1):

В `hibernate` есть такой параметр как `lazy`, он то и отвечает за неполную загрузку.
В xml он указывается параметр:

```
lazy="true"
```

Пример:

```
<class name="Order" table="CustomerOrder" lazy="true">
```

Можно отмечать как всю таблицу, так определенный столбец.
В аннотациях вот так:

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Другими словами **объекты с такой пометкой будут загружены ТОЛЬКО когда вы обратитесь к ним напрямую!**

P.S. Хотя мне вот тоже зависимости не нужно загружать (точнее очень редко), так я в обще зависимости не стал указывать. Он мне всегда одни id дает, а я уж ручками загружу, если в этом возникнет необходимость.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в коде `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`, то есть вы явно просите `hibernate` вытягивать вообще все до разрешенного в конфигурации уровня вложений `hibernate.max_fetch_depth` при абсолютно любом запросе. Попробуйте указать `FetchType.LAZY`, а в случае, когда явно нужны связанные потомки использовать `NamedQuery` типа такого

```
 @NamedQuery(name = TestPage.GET_PAGE_WITH_CHILD,
        query = "select distinct p " +
                "from TestPage p left join fetch p.Child " +
                "where p.Parent = :parent")
```

В этом случае вы получите объект с явно инициализированными зависимостями первого уровня, у которых в свою очередь зависимости будут заменены прокси.

Ну и отвечая на вопрос в том виде, в котором вы его поставили. Да, можно получить Long[] id, если запросить только его через NamedQuery как-нибудь так

```
@NamedQuery(name = Person.GET_CHILD_ID_BY_PARENT,
                query = "select p.id from TestPage p where p.parent = :parent)
```

И маленькая ремарка в конце. По стандарту имена переменных, полей и методов пишутся с маленькой буквы, а имена классов - с большой.

Comment: Благодарю за совет и за ремарку, учту! ) 
Но я так понимаю, что NamedQuery можно вызвать, только если есть ссылка на session, а значит надо делать это через DAO класс, так как замусоривать Entity-класс ссылкой на сессию я не хочу. Если это решению для DAO класса, то тут я мог бы обойтись и иными альтернативами. Но все равно благодарю за подсказку! )